# Not able to add test cases to type of IRequirementTestSuite

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I have created a test case workitem using TFS API.When i am trying to the test case to IStaticTestSuite it was successfull.

```
  if (firstMatchingSuite.TestSuiteType == TestSuiteType.StaticTestSuite)
           ((IStaticTestSuite)firstMatchingSuite).Entries.Add(testCase);
```

But i am not able to add a test case to IRequirementTestSuite using the below code.I get "Cannot add or remove test cases" error.

```
   if (firstMatchingSuite.TestSuiteType == TestSuiteType.RequirementTestSuite)
          ((IRequirementTestSuite)firstMatchingSuite).TestCases.Add(testCase);
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The only way I found is via the TFS API as such (Using only what you wrote you have):

```
var store = ((IRequirementTestSuite)firstMatchingSuite).Project.WitProject.Store;
var tfsRequirement = store.GetWorkItem(((IRequirementTestSuite)firstMatchingSuite).RequirementId);

tfsRequirement.Links.Add(new RelatedLink(store.WorkItemLinkTypes.LinkTypeEnds["Tested By"], testCase.WorkItem.Id));
tfsRequirement.Save();

((IRequirementTestSuite)firstMatchingSuite).Repopulate();
```

It works, I checked!

Enjoy :)